# What does the "update" tag mean?

Tags: discussion

Per the title, to what does the [update tag](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update) refer? It has no wiki entry, but has been used to refer to all of the following:

- Updating a piece of software?
- The SQL command?
- "Updating data" (not via SQL)?

Problem is, they're all very different things.

Personally I think it should only be the first - software updates. There is no tag for "delete" or "insert", that's what [SQL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) is for, and "updating data" covers every other question in one way or another.

Assuming there's a consensus, it may be worth clarifying in the wiki entry and doing some retagging.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this tag is rather confusing. maybe we  we could split it into two tags, say  something like [Update data] & [software upgrade]

I also found out that there is already an [editing] tag, which is similar in sense to [Update data].

Comment: Note: There's already a http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software tag